# Adding custom folder properties

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I've been able to successfully add properties to my document uploads, but I'm not able to do the same to the folders being uploaded. I'm using the code below to set up the basic folder properties:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File newFolder = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
{
    Name = "My Folder"
    , MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    , Description = "Description Here"
};
```

And following this, I add a property using the code:

```
try
{
    newFolder.Properties.Add("PropertyName", "PropertyValue");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unable to set folder property: " + ex.message);
}
```

And the message I get in the Exception above reads: `"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."`

I guess my first question is whether it's possible to add custom properties to folders. And, if so, where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps someone out there, I ended solving this by first creating `IDictionary<string, string> props` and adding the properties as follows: `props.Add("MyPropertyName","MyPropertyValue");`

and finally adding `props` to the items when creating the folder:

```
Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File newFolder = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File
{
    Name = "My Folder"
    , MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    , Description = "Description Here"
    , Properties = props
};
```